# Varchar type equals numeric

Tags: sql, casting, varchar

I have created the table in SQL Server:

```
create table tblVehicleRegistration (
    vehicleid int identity(1,1) primary key, 
    registrationNumber varchar(5),
    registrationDate date,
    userId int
)
```

and executed the query as below:

```
select UserId from tblVehicleRegistration
where registrationNumber = 20012
and registrationDate > '2016-01-01'
```

The strange thing here is that `registrationNumber` is `varchar` datatype and 20012 is `numeric`, but the query is executed. Is it wrong the query written like this? Actually it is exam question for 70-761 exam and I need to know your opinion. What about these:

```
select UserId from tblVehicleRegistration
where cast(registrationNumber as int) = 20012
and registrationDate > '2016-01-01'

select UserId from tblVehicleRegistration
where registrationNumber = '20012'
and registrationDate > '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare a string to a number, the *string* is converted to a number.  This is by the rules of SQL.

Often, this results in a conversion error.  So, if any of the values could not be converted, you would likely get an error.  When these occur on implicit conversion, they can be really hard to find.  So, I strongly recommend avoiding implicit conversion.

Implicit conversion can also impact performance by making it harder for the optimizer to identify appropriate indexes.

The best solution is to store the data using the correct type.  If there are no leading zeros and the value is a number, store it as a number.

Otherwise, be sure that the comparison is to a string:  `registrationNumber = '20012'`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon Linoff. Actually I tested by entering varchar and it vailed to convert, because before that I had only int data enetered in the dable and the comparioson was done in int type. Thank you :)